# Populating A Spinner From Another Spinner Depending on Condition

Tags: java, android, arrays, spinner

What i need to do is if a certain item from spinner 1 is selected it needs to display a certain array in spinner 01
e.g
if spinner one selected item is Red spinner 01 needs to display level_array as the drop down options for spinner 01 else display cparklevel.
in essence i am trying to display how many levels each car park has. so spinner 1 containts car park names and spinner 01 contains levels

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.cparkColour_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);

    if(spinner.getSelectedItem().equals("Red")){


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.level_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter1);
    }

    else {

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.cparkLevel_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it as:

```
spinner_1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {

                            if(spinner_1.getSelectedItem().equals("Red")){
                            {
                                  // set adapter to spinner_2 here for "Red" selected
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                 // set adapter to spinner_2 for "Red" not selected
                            }
            }    
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {                
            }
});
```